# how to move 20dip margin left from center?

Tags: android, layout

i want to move a seekbar 20dip margin left from center.

```
android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_vertical"
            android:thumb="@drawable/seek_thumb" android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:layout_width="20dip" android:layout_marginBottom="50dip"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_marginLeft="20dip" />
```

but the above xml code shows it center only.

Comment: is layout_marginBottom working correctly?

Comment: I desperately need an answer to this so I can solve my somewhat similar problem

Answer (score 14):

I made a workaround with a TextView in the middle that has no content (and is not visible).

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/viewMiddleInvisible"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnAtTheTop"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAtLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/viewMiddleInvisible"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/viewMiddleInvisible"
        android:text="Some text" />
```

You would obviously have to replace tvAtLeft with whatever you want. Same principle if you want to have something to the right of the center.

Comment: I think u could have place a general normal view instead of a view!

Answer (score 11):

`android:layout_centerHorizontal` and `android:layout_marginLeft` don't work together.

A workaround is to use an invisible view, such as [Space](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Space):

> Space is a lightweight View subclass that may be used to create gaps
> between components in general purpose layouts.

---

So, for your case, inside your `RelativeLayout`, this should do:

```
<Space
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/blankspace" />

<ProgressBar
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_vertical"
    android:thumb="@drawable/seek_thumb"
    android:layout_height="80dip"
    android:layout_width="20dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/blankspace"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest answer, which doesn't require to pollute your XML with additional views is simply:

> Add a 40dp padding on the right.

**Rationale:**

Padding **belongs to your View**, so it counts towards its final size. If you add a 40dp padding, your View will be 40dp wider without padding.

And because you are centering, For every 2dp of padding, your View will move just **1dp** to the left, so your View will move only 20dp, as needed.

Answer (score -4):

Remove `centerHorizontal = true`.